# Why is this question not interesting or bad?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked what is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852240/most-semantically-appropriate-tag-for-application-commands in HTML. I am as such asking a question about how to go about following the web standards as closely as possible and very much interested in potential answers and points of view.

After a minute the question gets 2 downvotes, a close vote, and a comment that says 'that's up to you'. What is wrong with this question? It is namely similar to [CSS/HTML: What is the correct way to make text italic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108318/css-html-what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-text-italic) (75 up), or [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons) (250 up). I have read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and the question does not break these guidelines.

Comment: Those others are from 4 and 2 years ago,  Things changed.

Comment: @Plutonix, what exactly did?

Comment: The guidelines for the types of question that are acceptable here, and the quality standards. The [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) has information regarding the types of question that are (and are not) appropriate now; they can change over time, but the help center version is the current one always.

Comment: I really don't see the problem here. You could reword it as "What is the recommended tag to use", but it's essentially the same question, and perfectly legitimate - asking for guidance to choose between closely related HTML tags. FWIW, I'd go with <samp>, but it really doesn't matter much - semantic tagging only gets you so far.

Comment: @SteveBennett The way you ask a question is very important on SO. "Which HTML tag is most appropriate for indicating online software and/ or applications' commands?", which is what the OP used, is definitely opinion based.

Comment: Meh. I think that's hair splitting. If you *want* to read it as a request for opinion, you can. Anyway, I've had a go rewording it.

Comment: Is it advisable to remove the comments now that the question is (much!) better?

Comment: @Jongware No, it is not. The question is still just as opinion-based as it was originally.

Comment: @Louis No it isn't. The question is asking for a convention, not an opinion. Which is perfectly valid. If the answer is that it's subjective, then the *objective* answer is "there is no real convention for this." The fact that a question lacks a satisfactory canonical answer does not make the question itself subjective.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was opinion-based when it was originally posted and it is still opinion-based as we speak.

While there are some solutions we can probably all agree would be atrocious (e.g. "let's use `<head>` for this!"), there is a large set of solutions that are not objectively better than another. Yes, you can use `kbd` for this. It is a perfectly valid choice. You can also use `div` and slap `class="gui"` on it. (I would slap it onto `kbd` too, actually.) Or you can use `button`. One is not inherently better than the other. `kbd` may look good with the stock CSS that browsers provide, while `div` would demand that you provide your own CSS to have something that looks sensible. `button` might represent your actual GUI better than `kbd` ever would. Then again, you may not want to have live buttons (even if they don't do anything) in documentation because that would confuse users. If you happen to be using Bootstrap for your GUI, then `<div class="btn gui">` will more accurately represent your GUI and would have the advantage of being customizable to the umpteenth degree. (Some aspects of a stock `button` are not necessarily overridable whereas `.btn` elements can be customized at will.) On the other hand, if you're not using Bootstrap this is not useful.

All the solutions have relative advantages and disadvantages but **which is better really depends on the *specific project* in which the solution will be implemented and what *you* are willing to live with.** SO is not geared towards this kind of question.

Comment: The goal was to get different answers argumenting for different elements, give their preference and support it with reasoning. The answer with most upvotes would indicate the 'canonical answer' (as @Ant P) mentioned. Perhaps someone would bring in microformats... Your answer here would have been a satisfactory answer to the actual question, were it open. I may agree, but not approve, that *SO  is not geared towards this kind of question.*

Comment: @Tyblitz the way all of Stack Exchange works is to avoid these kind of discussion based questions. It isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site which will require answers to questions - not opinions.